# QML property binding depending on an other binding in the same component

Tags: qt, qml

Let's say I have a `QtObject`, which has some properties. Are there any drawbacks using a binding in an other binding in the same `QtObject`:

```
QtObject {
    // This is set by the caller
    property var myObject

    readonly property bool haveMyObject: myObject ? true :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething1: haveMyObject ? myObject.isSomething1 :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething2: haveMyObject ? myObject.isSomething2 :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething3: haveMyObject ? myObject.isSomething3 :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething4: haveMyObject ? myObject.isSomething4 :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething5: haveMyObject ? myObject.isSomething5 :  false
}
```

instead of this:

```
QtObject {
    // This is set by the caller
    property var myObject

    readonly property bool haveMyObject: myObject ? true :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething1: myObject ? myObject.isSomething1 :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething2: myObject ? myObject.isSomething2 :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething3: myObject ? myObject.isSomething3 :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething4: myObject ? myObject.isSomething4 :  false
    readonly property bool isSomething5: myObject ? myObject.isSomething5 :  false
}
```

Which one is preferable? The reason why I am asking is because by the Qt docs the order of evaluation is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that the order is fully undefined. The bindings are evaluated in an order defined by their dependency relationships. For any `dependant-dependency` pair, it is guaranteed that the `dependency` side is evaluated before `dependant`. Thus, every `isSomething` property is evaluated/updated *after* it dependency `haveMyObject` has been evaluated/updated.

Comment: I see, that is a pretty useful information, thank you. Can you maybe provide a link also, which has this information?

Comment: @Silex Just imagine the alternative, and then think of whether anything would work were the alternative true.